Is it possible to create a status logger from Boost.Log?
I have and am using Boost.Log. I want to create a status logger that prints a status message. Basically a log message that is deleted when the next line is printed. Is that possible? If so how do I accomplish this?

What do you mean by "deleted"? Can you present a code sample of this, without Boost.Log?
